# Nested Object in Array in Object - JSON and Mustache

Tags: json, templates, mustache

I'm currently working with a mustache template on top of a JSON feed, and I just need to get a node to pass through (or if I can flatten it, that'd be even better). Here's the node:

```
content: {
    assets: {
        IMAGE: [
            {
                assetId: "54480278e4b0b0844a228d67",
                type: "IMAGE"
            }
        ]
    },
 ....
}
```

I also need to rename the 'assets' property to something like 'images.'

I've tried with a lot of different variations on this:

```
        "images": {{#assets}} {
            "image": [
                {{#IMAGE}}{{#value}} {
                    "assetId": "{{assetId}}"
                }{{/value}} {{/IMAGE}}
            ]
        }{{/assets}},
```

but this is just returning:

```
images: {
    image: [ ]
},
```

Any help on this would really be appreciated so that I can get my data to come through. Thanks!

Expected:

```
"images": {
      "image": [
           {
               "assetId": "54480278e4b0b0844a228d67"
           }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: It is really not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to put a javascript object into the rendered template (presumably in a script tag)?  Or something else?  Please show what the rendered template should look like when all done.

Comment: It's just a JSON config file that I'm reading into Android. No javascript at all. I'll update the question with the expected output.

Comment: What do you mean "no Javascript at all"?  Isn't the desired output a Javascript object definition?

Comment: Nope, we're using mustache as a template layer over a lot of JSON to change how it models out and cut down on the amount of data we're downloading into the app.

Comment: What is the output then?  Can you please show it in context in your page?  Is it inside a script tag?  Why wouldn't you just use your own javascript to restructure your objects and then `JSON.stringify()` the result?  That sure would be a whole lot more straightforward (and perform better).

Comment: Like I said, this isn't a javascript program and there is no page. It's a configuration file (JSON) that's coming down that we're modifying via the template to give us different JSON. The output is listed in the original question. This is then pushed through GSON for model objects in Android.